# scp'ing using key file as a parameter, How can I do that if possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub events*$date*_QA.log $remote_user@$remote_server:$remote_location
```

Is the aforementioned script incorrect? Am I not doing it correctly?

I went to the `.ssh` directory and saw that the remote server is in the `known_hosts` file.

But, when I do ordinary scp without any file as parameter, it is still asking for password

```
scp events*$date*_QA.log $remote_user@$remote_server:$remote_location
```

How can I include the key file in my command?

```
sh-3.2$ grep server ~/.ssh/*
/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:server....com,ip_addr ssh-rsa Asine=jhjsdhfjsadhfjkashdfjhasdjfhksadjfhasjdfhj
```

Answer (score 75):

```
 -i identity_file
         Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public
         key authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to
         ssh(1).
```

Use `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: still asking for password
`sh-3.2$ scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  test_QA.log user@server:location
user@server's password:`

Comment: @tech_learner strange, as that works for me

Comment: You may have to use an actual path, as in /home/user/ instead of ~. That seemed to have made it work for me.

Comment: You want the local user's ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub content placed in the remote server's authorized_keys file.  It's usually in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.  You also need to be very particular about the file permissions on files in ~/.ssh, making them minimally accessible.  sshd is very particular about the file permissions.

Comment: On Mac OS X it only worked if `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` was the first option. So this worked: `scp -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem -r dir user@remote_server:~/` . This didn't work: `scp -r -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem dir user@remote_server:~/`

Answer (score 3):

This might help another noob.

[I know this is a redundant circular example but its good to illustrate]
Scenario:

1. ssh from Mac -> Ubuntu
2. scp files from Mac -> Ubuntu
3. close ssh and scp files from Ubuntu -> Mac

I had only created ssh keys on my Mac (via ssh-keygen) and shared them with the machine running Ubuntu via (ssh-copy-id). So I could copy files, while logged into my Mac from the machine running Ubuntu, but not the other way around.

Solution: I had to create ssh keys on the Ubuntu Machine and share them with my Mac. then I could successfully run the following command on the Ubuntu Machine

```
Mac IP: 192.168.1.40
Ubuntu IP: 192.168.1.38
```

**On Mac**

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id ubuntu@192.168.1.38

ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.38

# Now on Ubuntu
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id MAC@192.168.1.40
```

And now the following command should copy the file without asking for password to *MAC*

```
sudo scp -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa MAC@192.168.1.40:~/Documents/Fluff/Version-Control/tools/pull.sh .
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this:

```
scp -P <port_if_not_22> -i <path_to_keyfile> <source> <target>
```

example:

```
scp -P 666 -i "T:\.ssh\id_rsa" "D:\somePath\someFile.txt" root@78.24.82.66:/root/Downloads/someFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and corrected via these instructions:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

The instructions here worked flawlessly when I tested on my boxes (CentOS/CentOS).
I imagine the issue is your ssh keys are not tied to a username.

Example:
cat authorized_keys  # on Box I'm sshing/scpin' to
ssh-rsa BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH/zAcS4kD9pyPAjD3/gd5D1rcQa6IztCMR9yMXiGFnxviWsT8/oYevZw25k4yREuA8ibLKC9peH1X4LK1E+n7gq4TETexWkZbQ2XGLOX44eglra3MB4FShPg0cZXGcJWltPQ/y0Ay2A/KmaC14YrDfqwm7+ibTiUp4hOO8I6eIPmwwGn/2hs0SewJXisGqUx2v my_user@machine.local #username is tied to the key and is an authorized host